# Keep nuget configuration when Azure App Service Plan allocated

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I added private Nuget repository on Web App, which is hosted on an App Service Plan.

`nuget.exe sources add -name {name} -source {feed} -username {username} -password {PAT}`

But if the App Service Plan instances were re-allocated(scale-up/out, Azure mainternance...), nuget.config above will not be kept.

I don't want to add this configuration on the repository's nuget.config, because it contains a password. How to keep nuget.config on the Azure App Service Plan hosts?